# What happens if I delete the main profile in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, profile

I know that deleting the main profile is a stupid action and it is mainly my fault. I still want to understand the consequences and issues based on my mistakes.

I did today some really silly stuff I used in my Ubuntu Terminal command `sudo rm -rf taras`, which deleted all the stuff that I had on my Ubuntu taras profile. I was trying to delete other account but ... forgot to modify something.

Luckily I started deploying Ubuntu 2 months ago. I am using it as a secondary OS with Windows (double booting) so none of my personal files where destroyed but my projects, savings were deleted.

Can you please explain to me what are the consequences of this? Do I need to reinstall Ubuntu again? Or I still can continue my work there? In such situations Git really helps a lot ;-)

Comment: Do you have another account, that has sudo privileges, to log into the machine?

Comment: @SiKing no, I do not have ...(

Comment: Then recovery in non-trivial; a complete reinstall will be a simpler solution. But at least you learned an important lesson, maybe two: 1) create a second account (with sudo privileges) that can fix the first, and 2) backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything fundamental in the home directory. You would still be able to boot, though possibly you would end up in a tty login prompt. Alternatively, if it boots into a login manager, logging in might produce some errors. You would still be able to login with your usual credentials.